# Column visibilty based on the user security level in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, roles, ssrs-tablix, user-roles

I have a SSRS report which contains a table, The table data set type is temp DB. I do not want this report shows two columns related to the money for some users. so I have defined two different roles for users. One for letting reading all columns and the other one for whom should not see those columns. Now I want to know that is there possibility to restrict columns visibility in the table regarding to the users' role in SSRS?

Comment: you probably already searched on google, I found this article close to what you want to achieve. This is not straigthforward but may be of good help.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4477/sql-server-reporting-services-column-level-security/

Comment: @AnkUser yes it was result of my first search, but unfortunately this site is not opened for me.